# set theoretical image of $\operatorname {Spec} k[x_1,\dots x_n]_{(x_1,\dots x_n)}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We have the set theoretical image of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\dots x_n]_{(x_1,\dots x_n)}\to\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\dots x_n]$ defined by the canonical inclusion.

Is it constructible for a field $k$?

(Eisenbud & Harris, The Geometry of schemes, p210)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set-theoretic image of $\text{Spec }k[x_1,...,x_n]_{(x_1,...,x_n)}$ inside $\text{Spec }k[x_1,...,x_n] = \mathbb{A}^n_k$ is not constructible. This follows from the following facts:

1) Every constructible (or even locally constructible) subset of a Jacobson scheme is Jacobson
2) $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ is Jacobson
3) $\text{Spec }k[x_1,...,x_n]_{(x_1,...,x_n)}$ is not Jacobson

To see why (1) holds, note that an equivalent characterization of being Jacobson is that every locally closed set contains a closed point.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has been answered by user15654, but you may want to think about this question some more, and try to develop some geometric intuition for it.

Start with  the case $n = 1$.  What are the constructible subsets of Spec $k[x]$?  What is the image of Spec $k[x]_{(x)}$?

Now consider the case $n = 2$.  What are the points in Spec $k[x_1,x_2]$?  Which
sets of them are constructible?  What is the image of Spec $k[x_1,x_2]_{(x_1,x_2)}?

There are very nice visualizations for these questions, which you can develop with a little thought and practice.

Comment: Constructible sets in dimension 1 is just closed points, which are not the image. In the two dimsensional case, the image of the local ring contains only one closed point but the constructible set has more. So this argument goes also to higher dim case. Am I right?

Comment: @mqx: Dear mqx, A constructible set in dim'n 1 is either open or closed, hence either a finite union of closed points, or the union of all but finitely many closed points together with the generic point.  In dimension 2 a constructible set doesn't have to be either open or closed, but they are not too much harder to describe.  You may want to think about what points besides the closed point are in the image of Spec of the local ring (not just for answering this question, but for practice with non-closed points).  Regards,

Comment: The local ring consists of points corresponding to irreducible subsets containing the origin according to the definition of localization of a ring; These points pushes forward to the generic points of the irreducible subsets. A locally closed set containing a such point would contain infinite points in that irreducible set if the field is alg closed. Since constructible sets are union of locally closed ones, the image cannot be constructible. But what if the field is not alg-closed?Thanks,

Comment: @mqx: Dear mqx, The closed points are (by the Nullstellensatz) exactly kernels of morphisms $k[x_1,\ldots, x_n] \to \overline{k},$ where $\overline{k}$ is an alg. closure of $k$, so they correspond to algebraic conjugacy classes of $\overline{k}$-valued points.  So there is not that much difference beween the alg. closed case and the general case for this kind of quesion.  Regards,

Comment: So likely there is also infinite closed points in each finitely generated domain over any field, and they not differ much. Am I right?  You are so helpful, thanks!

Comment: @mqx: Dear mqx, Yes, unless the dimension is zero, there are infinitely many closed points. Regards,